# Instanciate an PApplet from a java application

Tags: java, applet, processing, japplet

I'm writing a java application in which I want to embed a Processing sketch through the inclusion of the the Processing libraries. I have already written the Processing sketch, but now I want to make this a part of my larger program. Is there a way of through a "regular" java application with a `public static void main` method to instanciate a PApplet and let this access data from the application.

When the program instanciates the JApplet the window (which has the correct size set in the `setup` method is shown, but the map I want to draw utilising the Unfolding library does not render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it's:

```java
PApplet embed = new Embedded();
// important to call this whenever embedding a PApplet.
// It ensures that the animation thread is started and
// that other internal variables are properly set.
embed.init();
```